# How to push the viewController after the next one connected in the storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

What is the strategy & API we can use to push to a viewController after the next one while retaining the view hierarchy?

So for example when the state of the rootViewController is one way i want to show a list of collections. When the state of the rootViewController is another way i want to show the details of one of those collections AND preserve the navigation hierarchy so that we can pop one level back to the collection and pop a second time to the rootViewController.

A possible solution would be to check the state of the rootViewController in the middleVC and have the middleViewController decided whether or not to push the 3rd ViewController. I'm not a fan of that idea because logic that belongs in the rootViewController is now in the middleVC and that seems like breaking encapsulation. Is it?

Thanks for the advice.

Comment: There are a few ways of achieving this. I would experiment with random ways until one reacts as you desire it to and use that. When you start making higher level applications, a lot of times this approach works best as long as you understand inherent strengths and weaknesses that designing something in each way would have.

Answer (score 0):

As I can suggest you  is to push your third view controller as usual,
the put you [navigationController viewControllers] in NSArray then insert your second viewController at index 1

So you are at the rootViewController *Controller1* index 0

you push your desired viewController *Controller3* index 1

then you insert *Controller2* at index 1 so your *Controller3* become index 2.

Comment: That's a different idea. Seems dangerous because you would be juggling the contents of the array and im not sure how much the storyboard would like it.